# Recursively transform JSON and add data with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'd like to use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to recursively transform arbitrary JSON files:

#### Input

```json
{
  "id": 123456,
  "name": "Test",
  "more": [1, 2, 3],
  "instance": {
    "id": 987654,
    "name": "Different"
  }
}
```

#### Output

```json
[
  {
    "name" : "id",
    "type": "number",
    "value": 123456
  },
  {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Test"
  },
  {
    "name":"more",
    "type": "array",
    "value": [1, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    "name": "instance",
    "type": "object",
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "number",
        "value": 987654
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Different"
      }
    ]
  }  
]
```

#### Transformation Explanation

Each key-value pair should be transformed to an object containing the keys `name, type, value`. While `name` should be the original *key*. `type` should be the *type* of the original value perceived by jq's `type` operator. Since Key-value pairs are transformed to complex objects, pairs on the same hierarchy become part of the same array.

Is this possible to achieve via [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/)?

Comment: Arrays stay the same, I'll adapt the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement almost fits what `to_entries` is doing. But you need to carry down the type in a top-down recursion (because with a bottom-up approach, like when [using `walk`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77322330/1), the objects beforehand converted to arrays by `to_entries` become indistinguishable from proper arrays when determining the type afterwards). So, a recursive function could set up type and value, and in case value is an object, use `to_entries` and prepend the name to it recursion results:

```bash
def f: {
  type: type,
  value: (objects |= (to_entries | map({name: .key} + (.value | f))))
};
f.value
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "id",
    "type": "number",
    "value": 123456
  },
  {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Test"
  },
  {
    "name": "more",
    "type": "array",
    "value": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "instance",
    "type": "object",
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "number",
        "value": 987654
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "Different"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i9rbtKFMg2p)

A note regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77322217/recursively-transform-json-and-add-data-with-jq/77322330#comment136314316_77322217) that arrays should "stay the same": While this clarified that arrays should not be transformed (e.g. using numeric indices as their items' "names"), it's still unclear whether you want array items that are again objects themselves also be transformed or not (while staying inside the untransformed array). For example, change `[1, 2, 3]` in your example to `[1, {"x":2}, 3]`. The above assumes that this array should be reproduced as is ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/t_9TxMWE7S8)). If, however, you want the recursion to be propagated down into array items as well, also update arrays (before objects, to not run into the bottom-up issue), e.g. using `arrays |= map(f.value) | objects |= …` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6UAQudofLqt)), which would produce `[1, [{"name": "x", "type": "number", "value": 2}], 3]` for the altered example.

Comment: Looks awesome, I'll check it out asap.

Answer (score 0):

Incase it is useful, here's a solution that transforms the elements of both arrays and objects to show their types ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/O6aep2bS2Qr)):

```
def transform: 
  [to_entries[] | { type : .value.type, name : .key, value : .value.value }];
  
walk({ type : type, value: (if type == "object" then transform else . end)} )
```

For this input:

```json
{
  "id": 123456,
  "name": "Test",
  "more": [1, 2, { "c" : 1 }],
  "instance": {
    "id": 987654,
    "name": { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
  }
}
```

It will produce this output:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "value": [
    {
      "type": "number",
      "name": "id",
      "value": 123456
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "name": "name",
      "value": "Test"
    },
    {
      "type": "array",
      "name": "more",
      "value": [
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "number",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "value": [
            {
              "type": "number",
              "name": "c",
              "value": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "name": "instance",
      "value": [
        {
          "type": "number",
          "name": "id",
          "value": 987654
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "name": "name",
          "value": [
            {
              "type": "number",
              "name": "a",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "type": "number",
              "name": "b",
              "value": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: On the command line I get an error message: `jq -f filter.jq test.json`
```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 4:
walk({ type : type, value: (if type == "object" then transform end )} )
jq: error: Possibly unterminated 'if' statement at <top-level>, line 4:
walk({ type : type, value: (if type == "object" then transform end )} )
jq: 2 compile errors
```

Comment: @urbanSoft - It looks like jq 1.6 does not have an implicit else that returns `.` and so I updated the if expression to include an explict else i.e., `(if type == "object" then transform else . end)`. It should now work in 1.6 or 1.7.